# Setting up data such that the cells with formulas autofill with the rest of my data after pasting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm running a macros that pastes data into another work book. The data is updated monthly, and it is pasted into the next blank cell. 
The new data depends on formulas in the destination workbook, so the macros re-selects to autofill the cells. 
How do it make it such that the autofill happens right after the data is pasted, picking up from the next blank spot?

This is what it looks like:
So I want the range to be from the next blank spot...right now it picks up from the data recorded in the Macros.

```
Range("B30289:E30289").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B30289:E40021")
Range("B30289:E40021").Select
Range("I30289:S30289").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I30289:S40021")
Range("I30289:S40021").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

```
Sheets("Source").Range("<DataRange>").Copy Sheets("Target").Range("B1048576").End(XlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

Where  is the range you want to copy. Ex.: "B30289:E40021". But you must be sure the Source range is always the same.

Now if you want to have it dynamic too you can use for instance:

```
Sheets("Source").Range("B2:E" & Sheets("Source").Range("E1048576").End(XlUp).Row).Copy Sheets("Target").Range("B1048576").End(XlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

This will make a copy of all data Source sheet from "B2" to "E" to be copied to first blank row of Target sheet.

Comment: not sure what to add in the source? also, the sheet is dynamic as the data is updated every month.